# Как сделать прозрачный фон у картинок

Tags: html, css

Ребят такой вопрос, как сделать прозрачный фон у картинки, примерно такой, и что бы у каждой картинки отдельно. Я вро де бы задал img background но он не применился, может вёрстка не правильная или я не к тому элементу стиль прописывал.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.row-t {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.row-t img {
  background: rgba(161, 21, 207, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<section class="portfolio">
  <div class="row-t">
    <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/2/8/9bb2207023c03ce845958e9cc0d7c58e-full.png" alt="">
    <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/2/8/4fcb63982c99f01c3c1dc8c411f2493f-full.png" alt="">
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй `opacity` для картинки, а фон задай контейнеру:

```css
.row-t {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background: rgb(161, 21, 207);
}

.row-t img {
  opacity: .5;
}

.row-t img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<section class="portfolio">
  <div class="row-t">
    <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/2/8/9bb2207023c03ce845958e9cc0d7c58e-full.png" alt="">
    <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/2/8/4fcb63982c99f01c3c1dc8c411f2493f-full.png" alt="">
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: да я бы и не против, просто не знаю получится ли эффект при наведении на картинку, там получается ховер эфект. Я думаю он будет юзатся на целый фон.

Comment: @BraFik, добавил наведение.

Comment: Большое спасибо